# How I use Database Snapshot Services correct

Tags: validator, nodes, networking, block, hash

I want use Database Snapshot Services, because making genesis to last block takes too much time.... so I used `POLKACHU` site, the code is.

" curl -o - -L https://snapshots.polkachu.com/snapshots/polkadot/polkadot_16262141.tar.lz4 | lz4 -c -d - | tar -x -C YOUR_DATABASE_LOCATION "

### location changed like this

"curl -o - -L https://snapshots.polkachu.com/snapshots/polkadot/polkadot_16262141.tar.lz4 | lz4 -c -d - | tar -x -C ~/.local/share/polkadot/chains/polkadot"

All seems well downloaded, and I use the command
"polkadot  --database=RocksDb --pruning=1000"
but nothing changed, when i see telemetry, it start from zero.......

@hat is the problem?? Did I miss something??

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the location by following these steps:

1. Delete the `~/.local/share/polkadot` directory.
2. Execute the command `polkadot` directly.
3. Press ctrl-c to stop the process.
4. Examine the folder structure of `~/.local/share/polkadot`.
5. Locate and copy the `db` folder from your downloaded files (named `db`).
6. Replace polkadot's existing `db` folder with the downloaded one.

---

Additionally, consider using the latest version of Polkadot and include the flag `--sync warp`. This option allows for faster synchronization without needing to download all data initially.

Comment: thank u so much i will try~ have a happy day~~!!